# The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~\\images\\594083964.jpg' is not rooted

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~\images\594083964.jpg' is not rooted.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~\images\594083964.jpg' is not rooted.

Source Error:

```
Line 27:     {
Line 28: 
Line 29:         fu1.SaveAs(@"~\\images\\" + i + fu1.FileName.Substring(fu1.FileName.Length - 4, 4));
Line 30: path = "~\\images\\"+i + fu1.FileName.Substring(fu1.FileName.Length-4,4);
Line 31: }
```

Source File: e:\PEOPLE\Ravi\new data\WebSite1\signup.aspx.cs    Line: 29

Comment: I think you can assume he doesn't want the error ;)

Answer (score 21):

The path you are saving to is a relative URL. You need to save to a local file path (or full network path).

Try:

```
string relativePath = @"~\images\"+ i + Path.GetExtension(fu1.FileName);
fu1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(relativePath));
```

(Path.GetExtension(string) will handle file extensions that aren't 3 characters too)

Comment: Although you should use / in the relative path, not \.

Comment: @Guffa Are you sure that makes any difference?

Comment: The method may be nice enough to convert the incorrect separators to the correct ones, but there is no reason to rely on that behavior (that might change) when you can just as easily use the correct separators instead.