# Get Path to images folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, exception

I'm trying to upload pictures to a folder (located in my project folder) using `asp:FileUpload`.

I'm getting this error when i click the button:

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 'localhost:49256/bilder' is not rooted.

Here's my code behind:

```
protected void ladda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = filuppladdare.FileName;
    string description = desc.Text;

    if (filuppladdare.HasFile)
    {
        filuppladdare.PostedFile.SaveAs(\localhost:21212\pictures");
    }
}
```

I have only guessed the Path. What should it be? Or how do i get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~\\images\\594083964.jpg' is not rooted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350977/the-saveas-method-is-configured-to-require-a-rooted-path-and-the-path-image)

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206662/the-saveas-method-is-configured-to-require-a-rooted-path-and-the-path-fp-is-n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `MapPath` method to get the physical path of a folder:

```
filuppladdare.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/pictures"));
```

The `~` in the path represents the application root.

Comment: Server.MapPath documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: seems to work, but now I'm getting "Access to the path 'thecorrectpathon my disk...\visual studio 2010\Projects\labb6\labb6\bilder' is denied." instead, when trying to upload. So the path seems to be right

Comment: @guffa see above :) (do i have to write @ your username for you to see my question?)

Comment: @tobbe: Yes, you need to give write permission to the folder for the user account running the code. I get notified when you comment my answer without the @, but this is a forum, not a chat, so it may take a while before you get an answer. :)

Comment: oh, hehe sorry. Didn't know how it works. But now I do, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The path to use refers to a [physical path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) on your server (or in another accessible FS path), not to a url of your website.

If you want to get the physical path from the url you should use `Server.MapPath(yourUrl)`

Comment: seems to work, but now I'm getting "Access to the path 'thecorrectpathon my disk...\visual studio 2010\Projects\labb6\labb6\bilder' is denied." instead, when trying to upload. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Check your folder security properties, and also check that the website is running in an Application Pool that can properly access the FS, and that the user running the IIS process has access too... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
filuppladdare.PostedFile.SaveAs("~/Project name/.../pictures");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to get the current path, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx#sectionToggle1) shows you how to use various properties from HttpContext to find paths:

in your example, you could use the following:

```
filuppladdare.PostedFile.SaveAs("~\pictures");
```

The `~` tells it to start from the root of your application.

You could also use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use Server MapPath and sencond check folder permissions may be that can help